# Creating signals in vapi files

Tags: vala, vapi

I'm trying to write a VAPI file to use libui (https://github.com/andlabs/libui) in Vala.

I don't know how to connect events from the controls to vala signals.

In the libui headers is, for example of closing a window, this method defined:

```
_UI_EXTERN void uiWindowOnClosing(uiWindow *w, int (*f)(uiWindow *w, void *data), void *data);
```

In the C examples this method is called with the method "onClosing" as argument:

```
uiWindowOnClosing(w, onClosing, NULL);
```

How can I make something like:

```
window.OnClosing.connect(()=>{print("End");});
```

Answer (score 2):

Signals in Vala are implemented using GLib's signals, which is an example of the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). To use signals in Vala the class needs to inherit from `Object` and it doesn't look like `libui` is using GLib's GObject. So it won't be possible to use signals in this binding. Although it is possible to use signals in a Vala binding. For example the [gtksourceview VAPI](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/blob/master/vapi/gtksourceview-2.0.vapi) binds the `redo` and `undo` signals of `SourceBuffer`.

The pattern used in `uiWindowOnClosing` is to pass a C function pointer to use as the callback. On the Vala side these are called [delegates](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LegacyBindings#Delegates). `libui` hasn't added a typedef for the function point, so Vala needs to generate that. This is indicated by using `[CCode (has_typedef = false)]` in the VAPI.

The other problem here is the void pointer for the user data - `void *data`. This is probably best bound using simple generics.

A rough cut at a binding would be:

```
[CCode (cname = "uiWindow")]
public class Window {
  [CCode (has_typedef = false, simple_generics = true)]
  public delegate int Callback<T> (T data);

  [CCode (cname = "uiWindowOnClosing", simple_generics = true)]
  public void on_closing<K> (Callback callback, K data);
}
```

This is untested, but should give you a better idea of the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Vala's `signal` mechanism is based on GLib's [signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html) system. You can make these use lambdas, but not signals.

Answer (score 0):

using your code in the vapi and call it with this:

```
w.on_closing(()=>{Quit();return 0;}, null);
```

brings this message:

```
error: too many arguments to function ‘uiWindowOnClosing’
uiWindowOnClosing (_tmp3_, ___lambda4__ui_window_callback, NULL, NULL);
```

But this works:

```
public void on_closing (Callback callback);
```

in the vapi, and

```
w.on_closing(()=>{Quit();return 0;});
```

in the vala code.

Thank you for your help.